# Implement Okta authentication from Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, saml, okta, okta-api

I am working for AngularJS web application and we need to implement the OKTA authentication from Web Api.

Is there any possible to way to implement the OKTA authentication from Web Api ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Authentication API http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/design_principles.html#authentication to build your own login page and authenticate user using Okta.

You can also use sign in widget from Okta for  or use http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/okta_auth_sdk in your angular js.